# In React, why do we call this in arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions, es6-class

I have a question.. please let me know..

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
     console.log("clicking")
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.letters.map((letter) => (
            <li  onClick={() => this.handleClick()}> // when clicking li, it works.
            <li  onClick={() => handleClick()}> // when clicking li, it does not works why????
              hello
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is very simple code.

My question is why we do write like this.handleClick ??

In my thinking,

- When clicking li tag.
- this.handleClick function is in arrow function!!
- so, arrow function binds this automatically
- (in this case, this is bound to App component)
- therefore, in arrow function, just handleClick can be found, (// in my thinking)
- Because this.handleClick can be found!
- But, just writing handleClick is not worked.. ? why ??
  // handleClick does not found error...

Can you explain why this happen?

Additionally..

if I changed code like <li onClick={() => console.log(this)} />

We can see this is App component.
Also in App component, we can see handleClick function...

So, this is bounded to App Component,
and then I think  in arrow function, handleClick() function can be found. but does not find... why??

Comment: `<li  onClick={() => this.handleClick}>` will not do anything, you're just referencing a function which doesn't get called

Comment: Because handleClick is a method of the class App and you need to specify this.method to access it. You could do onClick={this.handleClick} also

Comment: It should be `<li onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}>` or `<li onClick={this.handleClick}>`, not `<li onClick={() => this.handleClick}>`. And [referring to a local `handleClick` variable instead of the `.handleClick` property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572?javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object) doesn't work at all.

Comment: absolutely you are right, i edit post, But my question does not be changed...

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be confusing what it means for arrow functions to, in your words "bind this automatically". Technically, that's not what's happening. See the MDN article:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

They don't automatically bind `this`, they simply don't create a new `this` binding (in contrast with functions, which inherently create a new `this` binding). While you could think of it is "automatically" binding `this`, that's not really what is going on. A key point though is that it only affects what `this` means *within* the scope of the arrow function. It has no bearing on what `this` it *outside* of the function. So the fact that you defined `handledClick` as an arrow function has no bearing on whether you can use `this` to access it or not. It only affects what `this` refers to within the function itself.

All of that explains why calling `this.handleClick` would be expected to work in your `render`, but trying to call `handleClick` would not. There is no function `handleClick` in scope of `render`. There is a `this` (the instance of your component), which does happen to have a `handleClick` method.

Using arrow functions in this context is useful because you don't have to re-bind it. If your `handleClick` function needed to access `this.state` or `this.props`, it would be able to. If you defined it as a standard `function`, you would need to re-bind it, so that the correct `this` would be available when it is called.

As others have pointed out though, your code as-is probably doesn't work either way not. You should drop the arrow function wrapping them. As is, you are simply calling a function that returns the `handleClick` function, not calling it.

Comment: but in arrow function, if i changed code like onClick={() => console.log(this)}. we can see this is App component. also in App component, we can see handleClick function... So, I think this is bounded to App Component, and then in arrow function, we can find handleClick().. but does not find... why??

Comment: The question isn't why it doesn't work but why it would, like someone allready explained the different binding of `this` for arrow and regular functions only changes whats considered `this` inside the function context. e.g. `const log1 = ()=>console.log(this)` will log your App component while `function log2(){console.log(this)}` would log the function object. Either way inside your component you can't access either of these functions with `log1()`,`log2()` but you would need to call `this.log1()` and `this.log2()` for **both of them**

Comment: You are wrong... this is problem is related to class policy... in class, we have to access variable or function with this.func . In spite of in arrow function..

Comment: I find the reason